# Add and Change nodes in XML file with R

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing, openstreetmap

I have a XML(OSM) file that looks like this (small example):

```
<way id="86015" version="1" timestamp="2016-02-26T15:01:32Z">
    <nd ref="85642"/>
    <nd ref="85641"/>
    <nd ref="86016"/>
    <nd ref="85642"/>
  </way>
  <relation id="1" version="1" timestamp="2016-02-26T15:01:32Z">
    <member type="way" ref="2" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="12" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="17" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="22" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="27" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="60" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="65" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="71" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="75" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="79" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="84" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="92" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="108" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="112" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="132" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="150" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="166" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="173" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="178" role="outer"/>
    <tag k="type" v="multipolygon"/>
    <tag k="note" v="00000 ExampleCity"/>
    <tag k="plz" v="00000"/>
  </relation>
```

What i would like to do is use the `XML package` in R to apply some changes to the file especially the `<relation>` part.

1) I Would like to change the `v=` attribute

```
<tag k="type" v="multipolygon"/>
```

to

```
<tag k="type" v="boundary"/>
```

2) I would like to add a new node into all `<relation>` parent nodes

```
<tag k='boundary' v='postal_code' />
```

3) Change the `k=` attribute part:

```
<tag k="note" v="00000 ExampleCity"/>
```

to

```
<tag k="city" v="00000 ExampleCity"/>
```

Well I am able to find all `<relations>` by using:
(`doc` is the file name)

```
getNodeSet(doc,"//relation")
```

or get all `tags` of all `<realtions>`

but I cant figure out how to actually overwrite and add the part I need.

Comment: The correct tagging scheme would be [*type=boundary* and *boundary=postal_code*](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dpostal_code).

Comment: Thats right missed that. Now corrected.Thanks

Comment: Classic XSLT problem! Unfortunately, to date, R does not have a robust, comprehensive XSLT library. However, if you have any other general purpose language (Java, C#, Python, PHP, Perl, even Excel VBA), [executable parsers](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) like Saxon and Xalan, or even command line Bash and PowerShell, R can call XSLT transforms using `system()`. Please advise on what you have available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I m quite flexible regarding an answer. I have Python and Excel available. Im also open for a Stand alone Program solution if there are good tutorials available. The Problem is something like that is quite easily done with an Text Editor but my file is "big" (1GB) does crashing all non programming solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose declarative programming language designed to manipulate XML documents for end use needs. While R does not maintain a comprehensive XSLT processor, it can interact with other languages/software like Python and Excel. And even for the latter, R can mimic an Excel macro using `RDCOMClient` library:

**XSLT** Script *(save as external .xsl or .xslt file to be used below)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>  

  <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- CHANGE @v ATTRIBUTE -->
  <xsl:template match="tag[@k='type']">
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:copy-of select="@k"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="v">boundary</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- CHANGE @k ATTRIBUTE -->
  <xsl:template match="tag[@k='note']">
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:attribute name="k">city</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@v"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ADD NODE -->
  <xsl:template match="relation">
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="member"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="tag"/>
      <tag k='boundary' v='postal_code' />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>      
</xsl:transform>
```

**Python** Script *(using the [lxml](http://lxml.de/) module)*

```
import lxml.etree as ET

# LOAD ORIGINAL XML AND XSLT SCRIPT
dom = ET.parse('Input.xml')
xslt = ET.parse('XSLTScript.xsl')

# TRANSFORM XML INTO A NEW DOM OBJECT
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)

# CONVERT TO STRING
tree_out = ET.tostring(newdom, encoding='UTF-8', pretty_print=True,  xml_declaration=True)

# OUTPUT TO FILE
xmlfile = open('Output.xml'),'wb')
xmlfile.write(tree_out)
xmlfile.close()
```

**R** Script *(to call above .py script, assuming python is a system PATH variable)*

```
system('python "C:\\Path\\To\\Python\\Script.py"')
```

---

Alternatively, Excel can run XSLT with R replicating the process.

**Excel** Macro *(using [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759204%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object, late-binding here)*

```
Public Sub RunXSLT()
    Dim xmlDoc As Object, xslDoc As Object, newDoc As Object

    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set xslDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set newDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

    xmlDoc.Load "C\Path\To\Input.xml"
    xmlDoc.async = False

    xslDoc.Load "C\Path\To\XSLTScript.xsl"
    xslDoc.async = False
    xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save "C\Path\To\Output.xml"

    Set newDoc = Nothing
    Set xslDoc = Nothing
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

**R** Script *(replicating above, using RDCOMClient)*

```
library(RDCOMClient)

xmlfile = COMCreate("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xslfile = COMCreate("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
newxmlfile = COMCreate("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

xmlstr = 'C\\Path\\To\\Input.xml'
xslstr = 'C\\Path\\To\\XSLTScript.xsl'
newxmlstr = 'C\\Path\\To\\Output.xml'

# LOADING XML & XSLT FILES
xmlfile.async = FALSE
xmlfile$Load(xmlstr)

xslfile.async = FALSE
xslfile$Load(xslstr)

# TRANSFORMING XML FILE USING XLST INTO NEW FILE
xmlfile$transformNodeToObject(xslfile, newxmlfile)
newxmlfile$Save(newxmlstr)
```

**Final XML Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="CGImap 0.0.2">
  <node id="298884272" lat="54.0901447" lon="12.2516513" user="SvenHRO" 
        uid="46882" visible="true" version="1" changeset="676636" 
        timestamp="2008-09-21T21:37:45Z"/>
  <way id="86015" version="1" timestamp="2016-02-26T15:01:32Z">
    <nd ref="85642"/>
    <nd ref="85641"/>
    <nd ref="86016"/>
    <nd ref="85642"/>
  </way>
  <relation id="1" version="1" timestamp="2016-02-26T15:01:32Z">
    <member type="way" ref="2" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="12" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="17" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="22" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="27" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="60" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="65" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="71" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="75" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="79" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="84" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="92" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="108" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="112" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="132" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="150" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="166" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="173" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="178" role="outer"/>
    <tag k="type" v="boundary"/>
    <tag k="city" v="00000 ExampleCity"/>
    <tag k="plz" v="00000"/>
    <tag k="boundary" v="postal_code"/>
  </relation>
</osm>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there is a small problem when applying the code it reduces the `<relation id="1" version="1" timestamp="2016-02-26T15:01:32Z">`  to `<relation>` ist there are possibility to not change that part?

Comment: O.k manged to figure it out there is just a ` /`  missing. When changing:
 `<xsl:template match="relation">` to
`<xsl:template match="/relation">`
It works perfectly. Thx again you helped me big time!

Comment: Whoops! Missed that part. See edit where I add `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>` in relation template to copy its attributes. Glad it helped and I hope to have enlisted you in the XSLT fan club! Please accept the answer to confirm resolution not just for you but also for future readers.